Locally increase the size of an arrow
I want to show a sequence of reactions (for chemists, Cannizzaro reaction) on the same line. In my case, I have to write a long molecule (Ph-CH=O) on the arrow but I have a problem in my code: either I have the right size but the writing on the arrow does not work (with the command \arrow[,2,](start.mid east--.mid west){->[\chemfig{Ph-CH=O}]}
) or I have the writing on the arrow but not the right size (with the command \arrow(start.mid east--.mid west){->[\chemfig{Ph-CH=O}]}).


How can I increase the size of the arrow while keeping the text above it?
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-@{atoc}C([6]=[@{db}]@{atoo1}O)-H)-=-)}
\arrow(start.mid east--.mid west){->[\chemfig{@{atoo2}\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\ominus}}H]}
\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C([6]-[@{sb1}]@{atoo1}\chembelow{O}{\scriptstyle\ominus})([2]-OH)-[@{sb2}]H)-=-)}
\arrow[,2,](start.mid east--.mid west){->[\chemfig{Ph-CH=O}]}
\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C([1]-@{atoo2}O-[@{sb}0]@{atoh}H)([6]=O))-=-)}
\arrow{0}
\chemfig{[:-30]*6((-C(-[5]H)(-[7]H)-[2]@{atoo1}\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\ominus})-=-=-=)}
\chemmove[-stealth,shorten >=2pt,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt,thin]{
\draw[shorten <=7pt](atoo1.90) ..controls +(+90:8mm) and +(up:10mm)..(atoh);
\draw[shorten <=2pt](sb) ..controls +(up:5mm) and +(up:5mm)..(atoo2);}
\schemestop
\end{document}


thus?
you can also shorten the bonds of the molecule above the arrow
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-@{atoc}C([6]=[@{db}]@{atoo1}O)-H)-=-)}
    \arrow(start.mid east--.mid west){->[\chemfig{@{atoo2}\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\ominus}}H]}
    \chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C([6]-[@{sb1}]@{atoo1}\chembelow{O}{\scriptstyle\ominus})([2]-OH)-[@{sb2}]H)-=-)}
    \arrow{->[\chemfig{Ph-[,.7]CH=[0,.7]O}]}[0,2]
    \chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C([1]-@{atoo2}O-[@{sb}0]@{atoh}H)([6]=O))-=-)}
    \arrow{0}
    \chemfig{[:-30]*6((-C(-[5]H)(-[7]H)-[2]@{atoo1}\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\ominus})-=-=-=)}
    \chemmove[-stealth,shorten >=2pt,dash pattern=on 1pt off 1pt,thin]{
        \draw[shorten <=7pt](atoo1.90) ..controls +(+90:8mm) and +(up:10mm)..(atoh);
        \draw[shorten <=2pt](sb) ..controls +(up:5mm) and +(up:5mm)..(atoo2);}
    \schemestop
\end{document}


